# Left Outer Join not working as expected

Tags: sql

Perhaps it's because it's Friday and I'm just not thinking straight, but I would expect (and am trying to get) the following query to output all Users, with a `NULL` in the EndDate column if there's no timesheet. Instead, I'm only getting Users that have a Timesheet.

```
SELECT     Users.Name, Timesheets.EndDate
FROM       Users 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
           Timesheets ON Users.idUser = Timesheets.id_User
WHERE     (Timesheets.EndDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-08-15 00:00:00', 102))
```

The end goal being to find all Users that haven't yet created a timesheet for the given time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

move the condition on the `WHERE` clause to `ON` clause,

```
ON Users.idUser = Timesheets.id_User
   AND Timesheets.EndDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-08-15 00:00:00', 102)
```

The `ON` clause filters the rows before joining the table. The `WHERE` clause , on the other hand, filters out rows after the tables has been joined. Since you put the condition on the `WHERE` clause, `Timesheets.EndDate` with *NULL* values are excluded.

Comment: Nice! I didn't realise you could use multiple conditions in the ON clause. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your `WHERE` clause is filtering out the nulls because `Timesheets.EndDate` is `NULL` when there are no time sheets.

Try adding a test for NULL as well:

```
SELECT Users.Name, Timesheets.EndDate
FROM Users LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Timesheets ON Users.idUser = Timesheets.id_User 
WHERE Timesheets.EndDate IS NULL 
   OR (Timesheets.EndDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-08-15 00:00:00', 102))
```

Comment: Also good and thanks for answering, I think John's is a more precise answer though.